# Reading a QR code from an image instead of a camera

Tags: images, qr-code

My device does not have a camera, so all those QR code scanners are useless to me.

Is there a way to read a QR code from an image, possibly like an app registering itself as a QR code scanner and it (also) opens image files to scan the QR codes?

I prefer not to use online solutions since those online sites cannot be registered as a scanner.

Comment: There are many apps in the Google Play Store which can fulfil your desire. Search there and pick up one app.

Comment: Note that, some apps are there which can scan both from the camera as well as from images.